# How to persist data in tableview when i pop from tableview using navigationbar's left navigation item in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, tableview

i have a login controller when user enters his username and password and click on the submit button the table view fetches the data from the database and presents the data but the problem is when i click on the left navigation bar item on the navigation ans pop back again to my login controller and enter credentials and click on submit button the tableview is empty.What may be the problem

Comment: Can you be clearer on what the issue is? By left nav item do you mean a Back button or a submit button you have? Is the data related to the login credentials?

Comment: Hi @lostInTransit by leftnav item i mean the back button on the navigation bar and when i push again to the same table view controller through the submit button the data in the table view becomes empty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think you did a login controller code in viewdidload method. popupviewcontroller work out in viewwillappear:(Bool) method.Better once you login you may hide a backbutton